# Is Dijkstra's algorithm linear time?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, a-star

```
O(|E| + |V| log |V|)
```

Stupid question I know, but if there is a log is it linear?

Comment: In terms of which variable? It is linear in `E`, and `n log n` in `V`.

Comment: No, that is linearithmic w.r.t. `V` (the number of vertices), linear w.r.t. `E` (the number of edges). This makes sense if you analyze the actual mechanics of the algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

No, O(VlogV) =/= O(V) because the ratio of VlogV to V diverges to infinity

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question "if there is a log is it linear" is no.  Linear usually refers to O(N)

What this means is that it's dependent on the graph, and that the complexity can be measured more precisely by taking into account both the edges and the vertices. A simpler bound would be `O(V^2)` because in the worst case `|E|` = `O(V^2)` thus `O(|V^2| + |V| log |V|) = O(V^2)`.  In the best case `|E| = 0`, so `O(|V| log |V|)`, so the run time is never really linear.

Comment: ahh ok. Are there any shortest path algorithms that are linear time?

Comment: I don't think so - there may be for special classes of graphs, but for a one-algorithm-fits-all-graphs there is none.